# Docker container exits with code 2 with deploying node app to Digital Ocean via Gitlab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: node.js, docker, express, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Good morning all,
I am trying to deploy my node app to Digital Ocean via a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline. The pipeline is successful and deploys to DO, but the container exits with code (2). My Node App uses port 3000.  I am using pm2 to run the server, but open to not using pm2. Below is my docker file, and my .yml file.

```js
# ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> authorized_keys: use this command to add gitlab ssh keys to sever. Run on server terminal
# cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys Run this command on the sever on the terminal. 
# Both COMMANDS ABOVE ARE necessary.

stages:
  - build
  - publish
  - deploy

variables:
  TAG_LATEST: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:latest
  TAG_COMMIT: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHA

build-Node:
  image: node:latest
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - echo   "ACCOUNT_SID=$ACCOUNT_SID" >> .env
    - echo   "AUTH_TOKEN=$AUTH_TOKEN" >> .env
    - echo   "API_KEY=$API_KEY" >> .env
    - echo   "API_SECRET=$API_SECRET" >> .env
    - echo   "PHONE_NUMBER=$PHONE_NUMBER" >> .env
    - echo    "sengrid_api=$sengrid_api" >> .env

build-Docker:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker build . -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST 
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $TAG_COMMIT
    - docker push $TAG_LATEST

deploy:
  image: ubuntu:latest
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - deployment
  before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client git -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - echo "$SSH_PUBLIC_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/*.pub
  - ssh-add
  - ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - ls -ld ~/.ssh/*
  script:
    - ssh   -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY"
    - ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker pull $TAG_COMMIT"
    - ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker container rm -f my-app || true"
    - ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker run -d -p 80:3000 --name my-app $TAG_COMMIT"
  environment:
    name: production
    url: http://167.172.225.124
  only:
    - master
```

```html
FROM node:12.18.3
    # make the starting directory the current one
     WORKDIR /
    # COPY Package.json 
    COPY package*.json / 
     # install the dependencines within the app
      RUN npm install
     # Install pm2 
      RUN npm install pm2 -g
     # Copy Source Code 
        COPY . .
        

    # Have docker container use port 3000, that is the port that the node app is set to
     EXPOSE 3000
   # Start the node app 
   CMD ["pm2-runtime", "./bin/www"]
```

Comment: What do the logs say from the container when it dies?

Comment: Error: username is required
    at new Twilio (/node_modules/twilio/lib/rest/Twilio.js:132:11)

Comment: This error means that my api keys arent being passed, but my .env file is in my app folder. Part of the .yml file is to create the .env file

Comment: I am not sure why .env file doesn't exist inside of my container

Comment: I added --env-file .env to the docker run line before the -d flag and it says "docker: open .env: no such file or directory."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the echo statements and put them before the dock build command in the docker build stage. I wasn't using artifacts.